# which release of hdfs does hadoop 1.0.3 include?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I see hadoop is split into three branches, and the release notes contain HDFS fixes pointing to a HDFS release. Does anyone know the website where I can definitively find out the answer to:

hadoop 1.0.3 contains HDFS X and MapReduce Y versions ?

Comment: Can you please share your feedback on the answer that I provided. If it satisfies your query, please consider accepting my answer by clicking on the 'tick' symbol on the top left. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand all the three branches which include HDFS and MapReduce are packaged into a single release of hadoop and any patch which is applied to HDFS or MapReduce is a patch for the complete release. Try to visualize it as a single entity which consists of multiple components. Hence, there is no specific version for HDFS and MapReduce. They are associated with a single hadoop release. So, when we are talking in terms of a HDFS release, it is the same as the release number for hadoop.